# WPF PropertyChange is not updated when Property is called a second time in the same code block

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I send a property changed event for two different property values in the same block of code. In between is a Sleep Command. The Window does not update the property.

XAML:

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReferenceRunExecuting}" />
```

Code behind:

```
        ReferenceRunExecuting = true;
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        ReferenceRunExecuting = false;
```

Property:

```
    private bool _referenceRunExecuting = false;

    public bool ReferenceRunExecuting
    {
        get { return _referenceRunExecuting; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _referenceRunExecuting)
            {
                _referenceRunExecuting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReferenceRunExecuting");
            }
        }
    }
```

OnPropertyChanged:

```
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyChanged)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChanged));
    }
```

Comment: When you say "The window does not update the property", do you mean, that you expect the value in the TextBox to change to True for two seconds then back to False? If yes, are you executing the the code in the code behind asynchronously?

Comment: Have you debugged to check the `set` method is being called properly?

Comment: How is the window supposed to update when you block the UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are actually blocking the UI thread. It is not recommended to use `Thread.Sleep` as it will block. A blocked UI thread means a frozen UI.

You should wait asynchronously using `Task.Delay`:

```
private async Task WaitAsynchronously()
{
  ReferenceRunExecuting = true;
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
  ReferenceRunExecuting = false;
}
```

Also try to avoid string literals when possible as they are easily mistyped and make refactorings difficult (e.g. rename the property). Use `nameof` instead.

```
public bool ReferenceRunExecuting
{
  get { return _referenceRunExecuting; }
  set
  {
    if (value != _referenceRunExecuting)
    {
      _referenceRunExecuting = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.ReferenceRunExecuting));
    }
  }
}
```

Or take a look at [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and use it like

```
set
{
  if (value != _referenceRunExecuting)
  {
    _referenceRunExecuting = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The window cannot be updated when you block the UI thread that is supposed to be updated it. You need to sleep on a background thread or wait (sleep) asynchronously:

```
ReferenceRunExecuting = true;
await Task.Delay(2000);
ReferenceRunExecuting = false;
```

---

```
ReferenceRunExecuting = true;
Task.Run(()=> Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
    .ContinueWith(_ => ReferenceRunExecuting = false);
```